# Alternative for jQuery.support.cors

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, deprecated, jquery.support

I am updating a JavaScript file that uses **`jQuery.support.cors`**, which is now deprecated;

What should I use instead?

The application operates in an **`<iframe>`** inside a parent document and uses **`$.ajax();`** to send data to a different url.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery.support.cors = true; // This is now deprecated.
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate further to through more light on the context with the affected portion of your code and possible error and or nature of the challenge faced? That will be much of help.

Comment: I am working in one particular application that operates in an iframe of a parent page and communicates with other applications across several domains.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain how you're using this property, and any further information that will help people answer your question.

Comment: I guess I don't totally understand how the original method works, but I am also using $.ajax to send data to a particular url. I am guessing that that is why the support.cors was in there in the first place. I am updating the code.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is pretty helpful here. Firstly that it's intended as an internal collection and secondly it suggests the use of Modernizr instead.

> A collection of properties that represent the presence of different
>   browser features or bugs. Intended for jQuery's internal use; specific
>   properties may be removed when they are no longer needed internally to
>   improve page startup performance. For your own project's
>   feature-detection needs, we strongly recommend the use of an external
>   library such as Modernizr instead of dependency on properties in jQuery.support

Comment: Yes. I saw that on the jQuery documentation. However, I don't want to bring in an external library. I was wondering if there was an updated jQuery method out there or some way of doing the same thing without using support.cors or an external library? Will my code break if I simply remove it? These are my thoughts.

Comment: The [Modernizr download page](https://modernizr.com/download/?-cors-setclasses) allows you to choose which tests to bring in. I expect that downloading the test for CORS only would result in a very small download.